# Merging join fields on Looker Studio while blending data

Tags: looker-studio, blending

I want to create a blend in Looker studio to merge two tables using "full outer" method, and the field of both tables used as join condition to be merged as one.

Tue UI looks like following screenshot:
[image: Screenshot of the blend configuration]

I get a blended data source in which I've got two date fields:

[image: The two fields that I wish to see merged in my blended data]

Is there an easy way to get only one field only out of these two in the mergure directly, as we do have while eg creating a blend with the "left outer" on Looker studio ?

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not think there is an easier way because of the nature of the ```full outer join``` as it is programmed to bring back all data from the left and right tables.

Answer (score 0):

Waiting for an answer here, I will use the way I've always been proceeding before, ie using a custom query to blend my datasets (that are stored in Big Query).

For example, following query:

`with table_1 as (select day,var1, var2 from ...), table_2 as (select day, var1, var3 from ...) select day, var1,var2,var3 from table_1 full outer join table_2 using (day,var1)`

would give you a nice blended data with the four fields expected: day var1, var2, var3.

Let me know if there's a better way to go !